# Does Traefik show the actual average response time in its metrics?

Tags: kubernetes, traefik

My Traefik Ingress DaemonSet shows some awkard metrics in its dashboard.

Is it correct? I really doubt that my average response time is beyond minutes.

I think I'm doing something wrong but I have no idea what it is.

[image: Traefik Dashboard]

Comment: Any chance you have some websockets going on or other long-lasting HTTP connections?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Two of my backend are websocket based.

Comment: I confirm that websocket is the reason. The way treafik calculates the response time is Tconn_end - Tconn_start and when my ws connection is using long polling, the stat in traefik becomes ugly.

Comment: You may want to follow https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/3620. The issue will likely to be fixed in the next version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answered in comments, Traefik's stats are very literal and when using Websockets it thinks that's a single HTTP connect (because it technically is) which is lasting for minutes or hours.